# How do I attach multiple HTML files to a zip file in R?

Tags: r, zip

I want to create a zip file which will contain multiple HTML (created from markdown) files. Here is an example of what I would like to do and the code:

**Path of Files**

```
 [1] "C:/Users/SXC3GFL/Documents/Supplier_Ops_Parameterized_Reports/MVNDR_60457557.html"
 [2] "C:/Users/SXC3GFL/Documents/Supplier_Ops_Parameterized_Reports/MVNDR_60083983.html"
 [3] "C:/Users/SXC3GFL/Documents/Supplier_Ops_Parameterized_Reports/MVNDR_60009765.html"
```

I then convert these three files to a variable. Let's call it `attachments`, how do I create a zip file where I can place the attachments?

**What I tried** attachments_markdown is the variable where all the path names of my files are.

```
zip("Drill_Down.zip", files = attachments_markdown)
```

However, nothing showed up. See below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip` function to create zip files. Something like this:

```
zip("name_of_your_zip_file.zip", files = normalizePath(attachments))
```

Have a look at the `?zip` help page for more details.

Note that Windows uses `\` in file paths to indicate folders, but in R you will need to use either `/` or escape the backslash to `\\` - so I added `normalizePath()` to the answer Mikael's suggestion which will take care of that for you in the `attachments`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I had nothing in my folder which is the cause for confusion. Updating my question shortly with what I did

Comment: @Jaskeil Try replacing `attachments` with `normalizePath(attachments)`. It appears that `zip` does not replace `/` with `\ ` for you on Windows. I would also double check that you are looking in your working directory for the zip archive.

Comment: `zip` will create the zip file in your working directory, unless you give it a full path, e.g., `zip("C:/Users/Folder/OneDrive/Documents/my_zip_file.zip", files = normalizePath(attachments)))`